# How to display discord.js greeting message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I got some problem when tried my discord.js bot to send a greeting when somebody come in the server. I followed all of the instruction from documentation, but it doesn't change anything. My terminal didn't send an error and any commands is useable. My discord.js version is 12.5.3

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const lobbyChannel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'lobby');
    if (!lobbyChannel) return;
    lobbyChannel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}`).catch(console.error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code to this since the `.find()` method is only there in the cached channels which you can access by using `member.guild.channels.cache`. You will also need the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent when you declare the client if you want the information when a new member joins. Other than that, your code might look like this:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const lobbyChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'lobby');
    if (!lobbyChannel) return;
    lobbyChannel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}`).catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: I tried with that, but the bot still can't greet. Do you have more idea?

Comment: What do you mean? What is the error you get?

Comment: If there isn't a channel named as 'lobby' in the server where the bot is, then it wouldn't send anything.

Comment: But in the server, there is a channel named 'lobby'. I tried with another channel, and still not working